# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'dishes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Please help!!

I created a web app using react and connected it with node js.

There I need to pass status of a dish to DishDetail Component whether it is in Favorite or not.
If it is not favorite. I have to mark it as favorite.
Whenever a person click on any dish to make it favorite, an entry is going to be added in **favorite collection with user id and dish id**.

But whenever a new user logs in and try to add dish as favorite as very first time.I'm facing error that **×TypeError: Cannot read property 'dishes' of undefined** at **favorite={this.props.favorites.favorites.dishes.some((dish) => dish._id === match.params.dishId)}** statement in MainComponent.js and in **var favorites = props.favorites.favorites.dishes.map((dish)** statement of FavoriteDish.js.

**MainComponent.js**

```
const DishWithId = ({match}) => {
      if(this.props.favorites.favorites!=null) {
        if(Array.isArray(this.props.favorites.favorites)) {
          this.props.favorites.favorites=this.props.favorites.favorites[0];
        }
      }
      
      return(
        (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && !this.props.favorites.isLoading)
        ?
        <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish._id === match.params.dishId)[0]}
          isLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
          errMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
          comments={this.props.comments.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dish === match.params.dishId)}
          commentsErrMess={this.props.comments.errMess}
          postComment={this.props.postComment}
          favorite={this.props.favorites.favorites.dishes.some((dish) => dish._id === match.params.dishId)}
          postFavorite={this.props.postFavorite}
          />
        :
        <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish._id === match.params.dishId)[0]}
          isLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
          errMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
          comments={this.props.comments.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dish === match.params.dishId)}
          commentsErrMess={this.props.comments.errMess}
          postComment={this.props.postComment}
          favorite={false}
          postFavorite={this.props.postFavorite}
          />
      );
    } 
    <Route path="/menu/:dishId" component={DishWithId} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/favorites" component={() => <Favorites favorites {this.props.favorites} deleteFavorite={this.props.deleteFavorite} />} />
```

**DishDetail.js**

```
const DishDetail = (props) => {
    return <RenderDish dish={props.dish} favorite={props.favorite} postFavorite={props.postFavorite} />
}

function RenderDish({dish, favorite, postFavorite}) {
    return(
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            <FadeTransform in 
                transformProps={{
                    exitTransform: 'scale(0.5) translateY(-50%)'
                }}>
                <Card>
                    <CardImg top src={baseUrl + dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardImgOverlay>
                        <Button outline color="primary" onClick={() => favorite ? console.log('Already favorite') : postFavorite(dish._id)}>
                            {favorite ?
                                <span className="fa fa-heart"></span>
                                : 
                                <span className="fa fa-heart-o"></span>
                            }
                        </Button>
                    </CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </FadeTransform>
        </div>
    );

}
```

**FavoriteDish.js**

```
    if (props.favorites.favorites) {
       if(Array.isArray(props.favorites.favorites))
          props.favorites.favorites=props.favorites.favorites[0];
       var favorites = props.favorites.favorites.dishes.map((dish) => {
         return (
             <div key={dish._id} className="col-12 mt-5">
                 <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} deleteFavorite={props.deleteFavorite} />
             </div>
         );
      });
   }
```

**favorite reducer**

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const favorites = (state = {
        isLoading: true,
        errMess: null,
        favorites: null
    }, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.ADD_FAVORITES:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: null, favorites: action.payload};

        case ActionTypes.FAVORITES_LOADING:
            return {...state, isLoading: true, errMess: null, favorites: null};

        case ActionTypes.FAVORITES_FAILED:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: action.payload, favorites: null};

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**ActionCreator.js**

```
export const fetchFavorites = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(favoritesLoading(true));

    const bearer = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token');

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'favorites', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': bearer
        },
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response;
        }
        else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
    },
    error => {
        var errmess = new Error(error.message);
        throw errmess;
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(favorites => dispatch(addFavorites(favorites)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(favoritesFailed(error.message)));
}

export const favoritesLoading = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.FAVORITES_LOADING
});

export const favoritesFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.FAVORITES_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addFavorites = (favorites) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_FAVORITES,
    payload: favorites
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `this.props.favorites.favorites` is correct? Should it be `this.props.favorites`?

Comment: Also, you are absolutely not allowed to modify `this.props` as you do in e.g. ` this.props.favorites.favorites=this.props.favorites.favorites[0];` ...

Comment: No. It's correct. one for the favorite i'm passing for and other one is the array created in reducers.

Comment: @AKX I'm not getting problem at that line... Even removing that line haven't solve my problem. That statement is for another purpose

Comment: You might not be getting an error there, but you're not allowed to mutate props in React land, and it will lead to problems down the line.

Comment: Anyway, don't mutate props, and add a `console.log(this.props);` before the `return` in `DishWithId` and look at and/or add that console output to the post here.

Comment: @ATX well, that line only executes when this.props.favorites.favorites is not NULL. But here the user is new. So it is NULL

Comment: ... So if you _know_ it to be null, how do you expect `this.props.favorites.favorites.dishes` to exist on null?

Comment: @ATX Where to put that console.log statement??

Comment: As I said, before the `return(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && ...` bit in the `DishWithId` function. That way you can see what props are being used just before the problematic statement.

Comment: @ATX Because Whenever a person add multiple dishes as favourite. I have to indicate Dishdetail component that which dishes afe fav and which are not

Comment: console,log(this.props.favorite)  => {isLoading: false, errMess: null, favorites: undefined}
errMess: null
favorites: undefined
isLoading: false
__proto__: Object

Comment: Well there you have it; `favorites` is `undefined` for whichever reason (that's hard to divine from the code you've posted).

Comment: Yes. I know that... But i am unable to find the solution.. because that statement is really needed for other times

Comment: Please just first get rid of all the props-mutating statements. They will make it spectacularly difficult to really debug your code (since subcomponents could be inadvertently mutating their parent components' props; props aren't copied when you pass them down). You can mutate them into local variables, but mutating props is not good.

Comment: After removing that. I'm getting error cannot read property some of undefined each time i reload even with old existing users who have already marked dishes as favorites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, you could modify this line (in `DishWithId`):

```
(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && !this.props.favorites.isLoading)
```

with:

```
(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && !this.props.favorites.isLoading && this.props.favorites.favorites)
```

and this line (in FavoriteDish.js):

```
var favorites = props.favorites.favorites.dishes.map((dish)...
```

with:

```
if (props.favorites.favorites) {var favorites = props.favorites.favorites.dishes.map((dish)...}
```

Comment: Still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'dishes' of undefined

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the same initial value to on other `favorites` (in `switch(action.type)`). I updated my answer.

Comment: Still the same ;(

Comment: Getting this in console -                                                                                          
favorites:
errMess: "Cannot read property 'dishes' of undefined"
favorites: {dishes: Array(0)}
isLoading: false

Comment: Ok, so still only the action `ADD_FAVORITES`. If you log `action.payload` what do you see?

Comment: The FAVORITES_FAILED part is executing.

Comment: So, if payload contains error message, why you pass this value to `favorites`? Maybe you could update your code showing the dispatch of FAVORITES_FAILED action. Just to   see what you pass.

Comment: Code Updated... Check out ActionCreator.js

Comment: Very very strange. And of course if you change this line `(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && !this.props.favorites.isLoading)` into `(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && !this.props.favorites.isLoading && this.props.favorites.favorites)`, and before doing `var favorites = props.favorites.favorites.dishes.map((dish)` you put amn if like `if (props.favorites.favorites) {...}` error disappears correct?

Comment: Thank you. I applied your idea but with little modification. I just changed that error statement to this: - favorite={this.props.favorites.favorites ? this.props.favorites.favorites.dishes.some((dish) => dish._id === match.params.dishId): false} and its working fine now

Comment: Very good! I will update answer with my last suggestion. Happy to helped you. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

Got idea from Giovanni Esposito.

i just changed this line:- `favorite={this.props.favorites.favorites.dishes.some((dish) => dish._id === match.params.dishId)}`

to this :- `favorite={this.props.favorites.favorites ? this.props.favorites.favorites.dishes.some((dish) => dish._id === match.params.dishId): false}`

Answer (score 1):

Check condition in favorites such that in case favourite is undefined. It automatically sends false there...

```
favorite={this.props.favorites.favorites ? this.props.favorites.favorites.dishes.some((dish) => dish._id === match.params.dishId): false}
```